# Mapping an Array of User Data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm very new to JS and have been stuck on one issue for a while. My project is a card generator that allows users to enter a "dilemma", draw a random "strategy" card and then save the pairing. I'm having a difficult time displaying the pairing correctly.

```
let dataStore = []

let dilemma = "";
    strategy = "";

function saveData() {
    newPair = {dilemma: userText.value, strategy: cardText.innerText};
    dataStore.push( newPair )
    displayData();
}

function doSmtElse( element ) {
 
    console.log( "element is here : " , element , element.dilemma , element.strategy)
 

    for (let index = 0; index < dataStore.length; index++) {
        const element = dataStore[index];
        doSmtElse(element )
    }
}

function displayData() {
 
    console.log( "dataStore is here : " , dataStore)
 

    for (let index = 0; index < dataStore.length; index++) {
        const element = dataStore[index];
        doSmtElse(element )
    }
}
```

For the `displayData` function I believe I should be using the map method to iterate over the array but have been unsuccessful thus far. Any tips?

[Picture of the generator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d1vr.png) I've console logged `dataStore` in the `saveData` feature and it displays the correct info but I can't get it to show up in the Saved Info box. That's what I want the `displayData` function to accomplish. Let me know what other info I should provide, I'm very new to this process.

When the user clicks "Save Strategy" I've added an onclick in HTML that should save the dilemma/strategy pairing and display it in the box below. If you need all of my code, let me know.

Comment: There's not enough to go on here. Can you share your implementation of `displayData`, what exactly you want it to do, and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: Just updated my post. Sorry if I'm not posting the correct info, just let me know what else you'd like to see

Comment: What do you want to display? All of the saved pairs or just the last one? If you want to display all of them you will need to iterate over your dataStore Array. You can use a for loop for that or use .forEach(...) on the Array. If you only want to display the last one you could just feed the newPair variable to the displayData function as an input argument and go from there.

Comment: @mwallisch I've updated the above code by iterating over the dataStore array with a for loop (to display all saved data) but I'm having issues with actually displaying it on the HTML page (and breaking the loop from going on infinitely)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 

 
 
/* these lines are just for test purposes  */ 
var userText =  { value : "test" }
var cardText = { innerText : "test123"}
/* test end ... */ 


let dataStore = []
let dilemma = ""  //new Array();
    strategy = "" // new Array();

/*
* @param   
* @returns  
*/
function saveData() {
    newPair = {dilemma: userText.value, strategy: cardText.innerText};
   
    dataStore.push( newPair )
 //   dataStore = [...dataStore, newPair];
    displayData();
}
 
/*
* @param {element} obj1  
* @returns  
*/
function doSmtElse( element ) {
 
    console.log( "element is here : " , element , element.dilemma , element.strategy)
 
    return  '<p>' + element.dilemma  +  ":" +   element.strategy + '</p>'

 
}
/*
* @param   
* @returns  
*/
function displayData() {
 
    console.log( "dataStore is here : " , dataStore)
 
    content = "" 

    for (let index = 0; index < dataStore.length; index++) {
        const element = dataStore[index];
       content =  content + doSmtElse(element )
    }

    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = content  
 
}


 
/* these lines are just for test purposes  */ 
test =  [  1,2,3  ]
for (let index = 0; index < test.length; index++) {
    const element = test[index];
    saveData()
}
 
/* ... */
```

```html
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
 

</head>
<body id="body">
    

 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've iterated over the dataStore array with this method and while it console logs the correct pairing it seems to do it infinitely and without displaying them onto the HTML page. I'll past the code up above